# Design pattern to reuse code with different instances

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, design-principles, laravel-5

I'm developing an API and in the controller the `index`, `store`, `show`, `update` and `destroy` methods are all the same except for the Model that is being used.

How would you implement this?

I was thinking about a `ActionRepository` where I create those methods and will resolve the model somehow. I am not sure how I can reach the model though..

Really would appreciate some feedback on this ;)!

Comment: BaseController with the methods, and model/repository injected to the controllers extending it - off the top of my head.

Comment: Would it be an abstract class or what do u mean, could u provide a simple example? Would appreciate it :)! @JarekTkaczyk

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
abstract class BaseController extends LaravelController {
  protected $repository; // or $model or whatever you need

  public function index() { // your logic }
  public function show($id) {
    // your logic here, for example
    return $this->repository->find($id);
    // or
    return $this->model->find($id);
  }
  public function create() { // your logic }
  public function store() { // your logic }
  public function edit($id) { // your logic }
  public function update($id) { // your logic }
  public function destroy($id) { // your logic }
}

class SomeSolidController extends BaseController {
  public function __construct(SomeRepositoryInterface $repository)
  {
    $this->repository = $repository;
  }
}
```

Comment: How will I use the Request class in Laravel 5? Cause in every method I have to inject another Request object.

For example from the `Eventcontroller` I will need a `UpdateEventRequest` on my update method in my `Basecontroller`.

Comment: Then just adjust it, the way I showed is for basic L4 controllers. In Laravel5 you have much more power thanks to method injection and other cool features.

Comment: Any suggestion or tip for how I can inject the specific Request class to my BaseController method?